# PyQt 5 keyPressEvent doesn`t work for terminating App Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

*Good evening everyone!*
I`m just starting using **pyQt5** and **Qt Designer** in Python so met some troubles while coding the example below. No matter about buttons and so on inside the App, the question is about using ***keyPressEvent*** i.e. for terminating App by Esc button.
There are 2 files: one generated by designer, second one - where the ***keyPressEvent*** is.
Form is opening, but nothing happened to it pressing **Esc** butt.
Looking forward for your hepl! *Thanks.*

**ui_main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtQuickWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(MainWindow)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.bigWindow = QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget(MainWindow)
        self.bigWindow.setResizeMode(QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView)
        self.bigWindow.setObjectName("bigWindow")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bigWindow, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.dateTimeEdit = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(MainWindow)
        self.dateTimeEdit.setObjectName("dateTimeEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dateTimeEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(MainWindow)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Dialog"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**py_main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow


class MyMainWindow(QDialog, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.show()
        self.setupUi(self)


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
                self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `eventFilter` method, in the constructor:

```
qApp.installEventFilter(self)
```

Then we override the method:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
    return super(MyMainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, qApp
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow

class MyMainWindow(QDialog, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        qApp.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
                self.close()
        return super(MyMainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```